# Enabled selecting accounts but still getting all accounts in the auth response

Tags: authentication, plaid

I recently enabled being able to select accounts in the Select Accounts Pane in Link and even when the user doesn't select every account, when I fetch the response from the /auth/get endpoint using the access token, I am getting data for every account.

Is the /auth/get endpoint the correct endpoint for this? Is there a field that lets you know if it was selected or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, `/auth/get` will return data for every account. To see which account the user picked, you need to use the `metadata` object that is returned via the `onSuccess` callback from Link. The selected account will be in `metadata.accounts`. You can find more details in the [onSuccess documentation](https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/#link-web-onsuccess-accounts).